# Downloading simultaneously as many files as possible

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I want to download images from random generated URIs and fastest way I found is unstoppable.

I'm using pregenerated `List<string>` of URIs reaching about 400imgs/minute (about 8 times more than while using standard Threads) but i want it to continuously generate URIs and download new images until I say it to pause. How to achieve that?

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ImageURI;
    GenerateURIs(out ImageURI); // creates list of 1000 uris
    ImageNames.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(50).Sum(s => DownloadFile(s));
}

private int DownloadFile(string URI)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
        webrequest.Timeout = 10000;
        webrequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
        webrequest.Proxy = null;
        webrequest.KeepAlive = false;
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

        using (Stream sr = webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            DownloadedImages++;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                sr.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] ImageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                if (ImageBytes.Length == 503)
                {
                    InvalidImages++;
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ValidImages++;
                    using (var Writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("images/" + (++FilesIndex).ToString() + ".png", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        Writer.Write(ImageBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }          
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }            

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any problems other than your GUI blocking, because if you just want to know how to do some work without blocking the UI there are *tons* of resources out there that will show you how to do that.  If you have any other problems, you'll need to explain what they are.

Comment: I meant something else, I already eddited post. I want to be able to stop whole downloading process, and run it more dynamic not from predefined List. (As i mentioned after first sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your current code isn't thread safe.  `InvalidImages`, `DownloadedImages` and `ValidImages` all need synchronization.

That being said, you can do this more efficiently using async instead of threading.  Since nearly all of the "work" in this case is IO bound, async will likely be a far better, more scalable approach.

Try this instead:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ImageURI;
    GenerateURIs(out ImageURI); // creates list of 1000 uris

    var requests = ImageURI
        .Select(uri => (new WebClient()).DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri))
        .Select(SaveImageFile);

    await Task.WhenAll(requests);
}

private Task SaveImageFile(Task<byte[]> data)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] ImageBytes = await data;
        DownloadedImages++;

        if (ImageBytes.Length == 503)
        {
            InvalidImages++;
            return;
        }

        ValidImages++;
        using (var file = new FileStream("images/" + (++FilesIndex).ToString() + ".png", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await Writer.WriteAsync(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }            

    return;
}
```

Note that, with async/await, you no longer have to worry about synchronization since those values will be set on the main UI thread still.

As for pausing, there are various options - you could add a flag of whether or not to continually execute data, or use `CancellationTokenSource` to provide cancellation support through the entire operation.

Comment: This look clever, ill try it in a moment, but how to make it download continuously, not from predefined List?

Comment: @user2843974 Just chance how the input to these methods is generated.  That's not really possible to answer without knowing how the URIs get created...

Comment: It's just site name + random string after slash

Comment: @user2843974 You can just make a loop that downloads some # of images (with await inside), and a cancelation token that stops it.  Since it's using async, it'll never block...

Comment: It works perfect to me. I have tried async before but I was unable to achieve this since I still dont really understand asynchronisation. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Would it be any difference if  I change the LINQ to : `....Select(async uri =>{ var t=  await (new WebClient()).DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri); SaveImageFile(t)})`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a producer/consumer model in which you have a producer adding items to a queue and a consumer pulling items off of it.  `BlockingCollection` makes this very easy.    Create a `BlockingCollection`, have your producer continue to add items to it over time as you generate them, calling `CompleteAdding` when done, and have your consumer use `GetConsumingEnumerable` to which you can call your exact code on that enumerable.

You'll want both the producer and the consuming code to be moved into non-UI threads, so that they both don't block the UI and can produce/consume the data in parallel.

Also note that currently within your `DownloadFile` method you are mutating and accessing instance data, despite the fact that this method is likely to be called from different threads concurrently.  Doing things like incrementing indexes is not safe, because it is not an atomic operation, which result in your code having possible side effects.  You either need to avoid the use of shared state between these different threads, or properly synchronize access to that shared state.